# SystemStackError triggered by changing files while server is running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-3.2

On my RoR app development machine (local server, OSX 10.8.1, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.8) something odd started to appear out of thin air (of course…):

The Rails server collapses (all routes are killed, server restart is the only way to get it working again) with the following log entries:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70


  Rendered /Users/dekay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/dekay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/dekay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (14.7ms)
```

I have googled and found that the SystemStackError is usually due to an endless loop, but as far as I can trace it I have no such loop in my code. And the error does not seem to be in a certain step of application logic.

The only correlation between server crash and my actions is as follows:

1. Change some code in the app
2. Reload the current web page of the app
3. Boom, server gone, error message.
4. No pages work after this, error is:

   Routing Error

   No route matches [GET] "/"

   Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to debug this, please?
PS: I suspect it happened after a careless "bundle update". Can this be?

Comment: What gems are you using? Are you monkeypatching anything in ActiveSupport/ActiveDispatch/etc.? Also what patch version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I am seeing this on Rails 3.2.11 and ruby 1.9.3-p385. Gemenv: https://gist.github.com/coneybeare/4957822 Gemfile.lock: https://gist.github.com/coneybeare/4957828

Answer (score 2):

Debugging a `stack level too deep` error message in a `rails app` isn't easy, since the error could be because of a variety of reasons, and the error message isn't too helpful.

Some of the reasons leading to a `stack level too deep error`:

1. Inconsistency in the [gems & plugins and any other dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2188007/429758) of the application.
2. [Code syntax error](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/51430)
3. Inconsistency caused by [applying db migrations erroneously](http://t3h-butter-pecan.blogspot.in/2012/07/my-first-stack-level-too-deep-error-yay.html).

If the error was happening on system boot up, then this tip would be very useful: http://www.datatravels.com/technotes/2012/07/11/awesome-debugging-for-rails-boot-stacklevel-too-de/

From the description, it looks like the app works fine for a while, and then starts crashing - so the above boot up case might not apply.

One way to go about figuring out the problem would to isolate the specific `line/block of code` that's causing the error by using [printf debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405963/429758)

Also, it might be worthwhile rolling back the changes and getting the system back to working state, and then put back the changes incrementally to isolate the root cause.

It is quite likely the `bundle update` did trigger the error in this case; so would be a good idea to check the newly added dependencies and see if they could be the culprit.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The really strange thing is that it seems to hapepn in the reloader, when I change a file locally the server doesn't get that and seems to crash. When I deploy to heroku this does not happen at all.

Comment: Heroku deploy forces the restart of the servers; so it's probably not too surprising that the error does not happen there. Does the local app continue to work fine after a restart? Or does it revert to failing with the same error after a while?

Comment: The local app runs fine if I don't change any files "under a running system". It used to be safe to change files while the app was running,  I just had to reload the web page to get to the new thing.

Comment: Now when I wait a few seconds between changing a file and reloading the web page (not the server), it works. If I am too fast it crashes.

Comment: What files are you changing in development? If it is something in `config/initializers/`, the server has to be restarted. This answer has some relevant info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4880811/429758

Comment: No, the errors come with any changed files. I am currently mostly working in active_admin files. But as mentioned before: sometimes the crash happens, and sometimes not. I cannot figure out when.

Comment: …the error also can appear when chaning stylesheets, erb or rb files, basically anywhere. Of course for some file changes, like the initializers, as you mentioned, I really need to restart the server so it picks up the changes.